# "Unknown data type" error in jdbc call

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, date, jdbc

I'm trying to call a Postgres function in Java using a Callable Statement. One of the input parameter to the function is of type Timestamp. when I try to call the function from java, I get the following error.

```
ERROR: function insrt_data(character varying, integer, bigint, unknown, character varying) does not exist
```

My function signature is:

```
insrt_data(
i_cd character varying,
i_prog_id smallint,
i_stat_id bigint,
i_dt date,
i_stat_cd character varying) RETURNS character varying
```

My jdbc call is as below. StrtDt is a java.util.Date field.

```
String sql = "{call mySchema.insrt_data(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}";    
java.sql.Date StartDt = new java.sql.Date(record.getStrtDt().getTime());
Map<String, Object> map = jdbcTemplate.call(connection -> {
            CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(sql);
            statement.setString(1, record.getCd());
            statement.setInt(2, record.getProgId());
            statement.setLong(3, record.getId());
            statement.setDate(4, StartDt);
            statement.setString(5, record.getStatCd());
            statement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.VARCHAR);
            return statement;
        }, paramList);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `i_prog_cd`. The function expects a `smallint` as value while I was passing an `int`. Postgres's `smallint` corresponds to `short` in java. After changing it to `short`, the code worked!